# looking to use a div to display information rather then linking to pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to open information/content in a div on the same page rather then having to create many pages for a site.
what is the best way to achieve this?
I.E
[image]

Comment: What exacly are you looking for? something like Tabs, or popups? And what have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: Do you prefer to preload the DIV content in the main HTML file? Or rather dynamically load DIV content using XHR?

Comment: for the moment it can be preloaded, but for the final product, the content is going to be added into the divs via DB calls

Comment: Sure but you can either pre-load all of it from the database when the page is generated (e.g. using server-side code) or you can request each section on-demand via AJAX/XHR when each link is clicked on. There are upsides and downsides to each approach (possibly depending on how much content is in each one, what it contains, how many links you have, which sections are likely to be viewed most, etc etc). You need to decide what you want.